# useState() - doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a modal component in React. The logic is simple, first pass the variable `visible` as props to the component modal. Then the external component updates the state of the modal by controlling visible. But I got an issue where modal didn't turn off after the external component set visible to false, and it didn't seem like `setState` was in effect.

I have provided the complete demo code, you can see the log that the visible object is not change as I set a new Object to it.

Code sandbox [click to see demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-demo-3j4r2y)

I hope you can help me look at this problem, thank you very much!

```js
export default function () {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(() => ({
    m1: false,
    m2: false,
    m3: false
  }));

  const close = useCallback(() => {
    const s = { ...visible, m1: false };
    console.log("should be: ", s);
    setVisible(s);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("newVal: ", visible);
  }, [visible]);

  const props = {
    components: [
      {
        component: (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setVisible({ ...visible, m1: true });
            }}
          >
            open Modal1
            <Modal visible={visible.m1} close={close}>
              this is a modal
            </Modal>
          </button>
        )
      }
    ]
  };

  return <IntroComponent {...props} />;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSsJb.png)

Comment: now check your sandbox code i just modify recently

Comment: Thanks, but It still not works and you can check it through the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your Modal is not actually a Modal. It is a child of `<button {...}/>`, likewise when `button` is clicked, it will make `m1: false`, but the [event bubbles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling) up to the Modal onClick handler making `m1: true` again.

```js
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              console.log("Activated!");
              // When you click on the Modal component, this will also trigger.
              setVisible({ ...visible, m1: true });
            }}
          >
            open Modal1
            <Modal visible={visible.m1} close={close}>
              this is a modal
            </Modal>
          </button>
```

When you change the DOM structure you can see it works just fine. (side note: `<>` is syntactic sugar for [fragments](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment)). So this will work:

```js
component: (
          <>
            <button
            onClick={() => {
              setVisible({ ...visible, m1: true });
            }}
            >
              open Modal1
              
            </button>
            <Modal visible={visible.m1} close={close}>
              this is a modal
            </Modal>
          </>
        )
```

[@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367569/john) has the right idea, and while it technically solves the issue, it is more a workaround than an actual desirable outcome. See Q: [When is good practice to use stopPropagation()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815439/when-is-good-practice-to-use-stoppropagation)

Also when I see language like Modal, for your consideration is the [ReactPortal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal). However, it is a complex topic that requires some understanding about how the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and [VDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965738/what-is-virtual-dom) interact, and beyond the scope of this Q/A.

[View CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-demo-forked-873dwm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes!  I am now totally understanding why the Modal can not be closed , thank you answer very much ! It really helps me who is newer to learning the React , I am going to read the article you listed .

Answer (score 0):

You need to call event.stopPropagation() in order to prevent the button event from opening modal message up again.

```
 const close = useCallback((event) => {
    const s = { ...visible, m1: false };
    console.log("should be: ", s);
    setVisible(s);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Cool! Modal can be closed I just didn`t think about the event bubble, thank you very much!